# JPA how to select objects which don't have multiple attributes

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I use hibernate 3.5.4-final. I have two JPA classes.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "SPI_V_OP_OBJ_SUBJECT_VR")
    public class OpSubject_vr extends PersistenceEntity implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1858749317461707015L;
        /** id */
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "ID",
                nullable = false)
        private Long id;

        /** name */
        @Column(name = "F_NAME")
        private String f_name;


        /** type */
        @Column(name = "SUBJECT_TYPE")
        private String subject_type;


        /** okved */
        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "SPI_V_OP_OBJ_SUBJECT_VR_OKVED",
                   joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_ID",
                                              referencedColumnName = "ID",
                                              nullable = false)},
                   inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "SPR_ID",
                                                     referencedColumnName = "ID",
                                                     nullable = false)})
        private List<OpSprOkved> okved_id_mult = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SPI_V_OP_SPR_OKVED")
public class OpSprOkved extends PersistenceEntity implements Serializable {

    /** id */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    /** code*/
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    /** name*/
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Attribute okved_id_mult is multiple. I want to select objects OpSubject_vr with empty attribute okved_id_mult.

I tried

`select ent from OpSubject_vr ent where okved_id_mult is empty; (hibernate error)`

`select ent from OpSubject_vr ent where okved_id_mult is null; (hibernate error)`

`select distinct ent from OpSubject_vr ent join ent.okved_id_mult i1 where i1.code is null;(return 0 objects)`

Comment: "(hibernate error)" is not really useful for anyone to be able to help you.  The second form is illegal.  The third form is not at all getting the data you say that you want.  The first form should be fine.  So what is the error you are given?

Comment: in first form i get this error:
  Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: okved_id_mult is not mapped [select ent from ru.spi2.irule.javaee.server.models.rfm.operations.domain.objects.OpSubject_vr ent where okved_id_mult is empty]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Query is fine but you need to qualify okved_id_mult as ent.okved_id_mult.
2. It is illegal to restrict on collection attributes.
3. You need to modify the query to use left join. Then it is logically equivalent to the first query.

See the test case at https://github.com/BatooOrg/BatooJPA/tree/master/community/src/test/java/org/batoo/jpa/community/test/t2

Comment: Thank you! select ent from OpSubject_vr ent where ent.okved_id_mult is empty work good.

Comment: Glad that it worked - Meanwhile may I invite you to take a look at Batoo JPA - %100 JPA implementation that is 15x time faster then Hibernate... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the " not in " operator .This query will check if your "okved_id_mult.id " doesn't appear in all the existing OpSprOkved.id :

```
 select ent from OpSubject_vr ent where okved_id_mult.id not in
   ( select O.id from OpSprOkved O)
```